# Can't install neovim in windows

Tags: neovim, vim-plugin, neovim-plugin

I want to have neovim. I installed it with `choco install neovim` in the PowerShell (admin). Then I followed a lot of tutorials, like the one of theprimeagen, but I can't get pass the first steps. Maybe is because I don't have Linux, as everybody does, but I don't think is that.

I created a folder like so: `C:/users/myusername/.config/nvim`. Then, in this folder I type `nvim .` to open the Explorer of neovim and start creating the `.lua` files. The problem is that I always get a stupid `.nvimlog` every time I enter neovim, I think is the reason why I can't install plugins correctly or remap some keys.

In the `.nvimlog` every time I enter neovim appears a new line that says:
`ERR 2023-02-12T12:55:04.800 nvim.15716.0 terminfo_start 374: uv_tty_set_mode failed: invalid argument`. And I swear I followed every tutorial in the exact way, and even without creating any file the `.nvimlog` is always there.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, the default config directory is ~/AppData/Local, based on their [official documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/starting.html#base-directories). I don't know if there is a way to change that, but that is how i configured it.
To find out where your config directory is you can also use **:echo stdpath('config')**.

Comment: That is right, in windows is in /local/nvim, but I still get this error that seemed to be a terminal one, but with windows terminal is still not working